# PCF in cubemap (PCSS)

Tags: opengl, cube, shadow-mapping

I’m following [this paper](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.download.nvidia.com%2Fshaderlibrary%2Fdocs%2Fshadow_PCSS.pdf&ei=68e-VNe7EYvfaIWlgvAO&usg=AFQjCNEuzJ2ygiJ39MxbLNXXTpNiWyHjmQ&sig2=OTe6U7u1TfxsrtmAG_R4oA&bvm=bv.83829542,d.d2s) in order to implement PCSS in my engine.

I have a little problem though. My engine only permits **omnidirectial lights** up to now – I’ll add more later, but that’s not the question. So, in the first place, I implemented **hard shadow mapping**. It was a win.

I decided to turn my hard shadows into soft ones via PCSS. As a careful person, I decided to make a first shot at PCF to get my feet wet. And that’s a fail.

On a **2D texture**, it’s pretty straight-forward. I just sample several values from the light depthmap using a simple kernel, and I average them with a box / poisson / gaussian / whatever filter.

But how should I do that in a cubemap?! The offsets are directions, I don’t really know how to do that…

Comment: Did you end up getting this? I'm having the same issue now. I'm using a cubemap, but can't work out how to use a large PCF kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Using a cubemap, your UV coords are a direction.  It's pretty easy to get the light depthmap UV's from that.  Sample as if the direction is coming from the light source.